# Form with enctype return null file in request

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, laravel-8

I tried to edit the products in my store. On request, missing $request->file('image');
I'm attaching the source code below, I really don't know why I don't receive the image in the request, because I think it's correct what I did

My form :

```
<form  method="POST" action="{{ route('products.update', $product->id)}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @csrf
        @method('PATCH')
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Product slug</label>
                    <input type="text" name="product_slug" value="{{$product->product_slug}}" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="Enter slug">
                  </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleFormControlInput111">Product title</label>
                    <input type="text" name="product_title"  value="{{$product->product_title}}" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput111" placeholder="Enter slug">
                  </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleFormControlInput2">Product category</label>
                    <input type="text" name="product_category"  value="{{$product->product_category}}" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput2" placeholder="name@example.com">
                  </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleFormControlInput3">Product brand</label>
                    <input type="text" name="product_brand"  value="{{$product->product_brand}}" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput3" placeholder="name@example.com">
                  </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleFormControlInput22">Product display</label>
                    <input type="text" name="product_display"  value="{{$product->product_display}}" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput22" placeholder="name@example.com">
                  </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleFormControlInput34">Product ram</label>
                    <input type="text" name="product_ram"  value="{{$product->product_ram}}" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput34" placeholder="name@example.com">
                  </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleFormControlInput33">Product os</label>
                    <input type="text" name="product_os"  value="{{$product->product_os}}" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput33" placeholder="name@example.com">
                  </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleFormControlInput333">Product camera</label>
                    <input type="text" name="product_camera"  value="{{$product->product_camera}}" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput333" placeholder="name@example.com">
                  </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleFormControlInput8">Product price</label>
                    <input type="text" name="product_price"  value="{{$product->product_price}}" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput8" placeholder="name@example.com">
                  </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleFormControlFile1">Change product photo</label>
                    <input type="file" name="image" value="{{$product->product_image}}" class="form-control-file" id="exampleFormControlFile1">
                    <img src="/storage/img/tech/{{$product->product_image}}" style="width:300px" alt="product_image">
                  </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="short_description">Short description</label>
          <textarea class="form-control" name="about_product" id="short_description" rows="10">{{$product->about_product}}</textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="long_description">Long description</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" name="product_description"   id="long_description" rows="10">{{$product->product_description}}</textarea>
          </div>
          <input type="submit" value="Edit" class="btn btn-success" name="submit">
          <a href="/admin/products" class="btn btn-primary">Go back</a>
      </form>
```

If I remove the part with the image, the code is perfectly functional
My function in controller(type resource)

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        dd($request->all());
        $request->validate([
            'product_slug' => 'required|max:100',
            'product_title' => 'required|max:100',
            'product_category' => 'required|max:100',
            'product_brand' => 'required|max:100',
            'product_image' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
            'product_display' => 'required',
            'product_camera' => 'required',
            'product_ram' => 'required',
            'product_os' => 'required',
            'product_price' => 'required|max:100',
            'about_product' => 'required',
            'product_description' => 'required'
        ]);

            $input = $request->all();

        if ($image = $request->file('image')) {
                $destinationPath = 'storage/img/tech/';
                $profileImage = $image->getClientOriginalName();
                $image->move($destinationPath, $profileImage);
                $input['image'] = $profileImage;
        } else {
            unset($input['image']);
        }
        $product = Product::find($id);
        $product->product_slug = $request->get('product_slug');
        $product->product_title = $request->get('product_title');
        $product->product_category = $request->get('product_category');
        $product->product_brand = $request->get('product_brand');
        $product->product_display = $request->get('product_display');
        $product->product_ram = $request->get('product_ram');
        $product->product_camera = $request->get('product_camera');
        $product->product_os = $request->get('product_os');
        $product->product_price = $request->get('product_price');
        $product->product_image = $profileImage;
        $product->about_product = $request->get('about_product');
        $product->product_description = $request->get('product_description');
        $product->update();


        return redirect('/admin/products')->with('success', "product updated!");
    }
```

Comment: So note that `<input type="file">` does not support `value="{{ $product->product_image }}"`, you have to actually select a file to upload for the file to be present.

Comment: How can I do this if I want to edit something?

Comment: The user doing the edit needs to upload the file from their machine, or you need to handle the possibility that they do not upload a file at all. You look like you're somewhat handling that, but `$profileImage` is not defined if no file is uploaded, so you would have to do `$product->product_image = isset($profileImage) ? $profileImage : null;`, or wrap that line with `if(isset($profileImage) { $product->product_image = $profileImage }`

Comment: You suggested a very good idea that I didn't initially analyze. Thank you

Comment: But, there is a problem: If the user does not label the image field, the image should remain the original, but not null

Comment: Yup! That's handled by wrapping the assignment to `$product->product_image` with an `if` statement, as indicated in my edited comment. The first approach I suggested, using a `ternary` operator, will set it to the image or `null`, which could unintentionally remove the image. The `if()` statement will handle that a little better, only setting the image if it's uploaded, and never `null`-ing it out. You could handle the image delete in a different request, like a "Delete Image" button tied to an AJAX request, or similar.

Comment: If I use this check $product->product_image = isset($profileImage) ? $profileImage : null; , When you edit fields other than the image, the image field becomes null. I need it to stay intact

Comment: Then don't use that `ternary` check... In both of the comments above, I said wrap it in an `if()` statement to avoid that...

Comment: Ohhh, I'm a loser, at first I didn't understand what you meant. Now it works perfectly, thank you from the bottom of my heart !!

Comment: You're not a loser  I kept editing my comments too, which could lead to some confusion. But yeah, you could handle it a couple ways, I'll add an answer below to sum it up a little better.

Comment: Add as general answer so you can mark it as correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The core issue here is that `value="{{ $product-> product_image }}"` is not valid. `<input type="file">` doesn't support that, as the image needs to be directly uploaded from the User's machine, and unless a file is selected and uploaded, `$request->file('image')` will be `null`.

To handle this cleaner, use some conditional logic in the Controller:

First, upload the image and set a reference to the file:

```php
$profileImage = null;
if ($image = $request->file('image')) {
  $destinationPath = 'storage/img/tech/';
  $profileImage = $image->getClientOriginalName();
  $image->move($destinationPath, $profileImage);
}
```

Next, set the `$product->product_image` based on the value of `$profileImage`:

```php
$product = Product::find($id);
...
if ($profileImage)
  $product->product_image = $profileImage;
}
```

A `ternary` or `null-coalesce` statement can be used, but it'll look a bit weird:

```php
$product->product_image = $profileImage ? $profileImage : $product->product_image;
// OR
$product->product_image = $profileImage ?? $product->product_image;
```

Both of these cases will set `$product->product_image` to `$profileImage`, or the existing value of `$product->profile_image` if nothing is provided (that will be an existing image or `null`)

Comment: You just made my day. Thank you very much